# Facebook login screen flashing on iPhone app when already authenticated

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I'm integrating facebook with my Application, and I want to give users the option to post a story to their FB wall from within my app. It's my understanding this requires users to 1. login/authorize and select 'publish' from a separate screen to post the story.

My goal is to have both these events occur when a user presses a button in my app. The only tiny glitch I'm noticing is that if the user has already logged in and authorized the app, the login screen flashes briefly before the 'publish story' screen. Is there any sort of property I can check to see if a user has already authorized the application to prevent the login screen from flashing? This is the code I'm working with right now:

```
if (facebook == nil)
{
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] init];
}

if (!facebook.accessToken)
{
    [facebook authorize:@"###############" permissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_stream"] delegate:self];
}else
{
    [self fbDidLogin];
}
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your code.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the "Facebook-SDK" - or are you using something different?

Comment: yes, sorry, I am using the regular facebook sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casey, this might help you:

The main issue I have found with that flashing login-screen had to do with the cookies Facebook stores in the iPhone.

What I did is:

**1.** Store the facebook access_token and expiration_date elsewhere (NSUserDefaults might be a good place).

This way, you can check if the user has already authenticated. If the user hasn't authenticated, then you can show the login screen.

**2.** Another thing that is important, is to know that Facebook will save some cookies as part of the authentication process. So, what happens is: the user authenticates and then turns off the app, then the next he opens it and taps login; Facebook will use its cookies, causing that annoying screen to appear and disappear.

You can try deleting the facebook cookies each time you want the user to login. That did the job for me.

Here you have a code snippet that removes the cookies.

```
-(void) deleteFacebookCookies{
    NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    NSArray* facebookCookies = [cookies cookiesForURL:
                                [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://login.facebook.com"]];

    for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in facebookCookies) {
        [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
}
```

HTH, cheers!

Comment: Thanks @Lio / @Moshe, I appreciate the help. I'm gonna give this a shot and I'll let you know how it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use FBConnect you can just use [[FBSession session] isConnected], and [[FBSession session] logout, this is for old SDK, there are some changes in auth in current version.

Comment: He's using the `Facebook` class which suggest that it's the newer API.